# Tourmaline-Laden Ceramics in Hair-Care Products

Tags: electrostatics, material-science, infrared-radiation

I have seen a great deal of hype for hair care products in which the ceramic of any part of the product (barrels of hairbrushes (particularly the cylindrical *blowdrying* brushes), heating elements of curlers, straighteners, etc.) that *is* made of ceramic is made of ceramic with an admixture of *tourmaline*. I have found it impossible, trawling through the literature on this subject, to find more than traces & fragments of any plain scientific accounting for what the virtues are of tourmaline-laden ceramic in such products. However, from those fragments, I have gleaned that the virtues of it *may* be the following.

(I) That adding tourmaline to a ceramic brings its place on the triboelectric scale *closer* to that of natural hair. Thereby obviating much of the difficulties brought by the imparting of static charge to hair in the process of grooming it.

(I) That adding tourmaline to a ceramic lowers its *albedo* in the infra-red ... that if one could *see* in the infra-red, it would appear darker ... thereby 'widening the avenue' through which heat passes from the product to the hair under grooming with it.

I wonder whether anyone can confirm or dispel these notions that I have assembled.

Comment: Tourmaline is piezoelectric and thermoelectric. Maybe a nice student experiment, to see if that is noticeable with a hair dryer.

Comment: And also whether those properties persist when its just powdered down & added to a ceramic in _some_ proportion. Have you seen the _hype_ around hair-care products with _tourmaliney_ ceramic parts. There's strict _manners_ about _hype_ (even if it _is __counterhype___!) on this site - so I didn't say it in the main body; but it's enough to thoroughly disgust anyone who cae

Comment: cares atall about integrity in the conveyance of sound physics. All the talk about it being "a copious _emitter_ of negative ions" (which are highly conducive to well-being, apparantly), and "ionic technology"  just means that its place on the triboelectric scale is somewhat towards the electron _donating_ end - roughly at the same poitnt as hair. Cosmetics is one of the _worst_ playgrounds for that kind of _beglamouring_!